# Decryption issue when padded characters come

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

> I enter the name of archive in a textbox to get the message of this archive.
>
> I write password in a textbox
>
> I Calculate the salt.

Button Click

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String message;
        String password;
        String result;
        String resultSalt;
        String nameResult;
        byte[] salt;


        password = textBox2.Text;
        nameResult = textBox3.Text;
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[16]);

        resultSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            message = readArchive();
            result = Encrypt(message,password,resultSalt);
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(nameResult, result);
                MessageBox.Show("Encrypt Ok");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            message = readArchive();
            result = Decrypt(message,password,result);
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(nameResult, resultSalt);
                MessageBox.Show("Decrypt OK");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }
    }
```

Method Encrypt

```
    public static string Encrypt(string message, string pass, string salt)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt), 9);
        byte[] key = rgb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] iv = rgb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize >> 3);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] dataencrypt = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(dataencrypt);
    }
```

Method decrypt

```
    public static string Decrypt(string message, string pass, string salt)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt), 9);
        byte[] key = rgb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] iv = rgb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize >> 3);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        byte[] datadecrypt = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(datadecrypt);
    }
```

Method readArchive

```
    private string readArchive()
    {
        String nameArchive = textBox1.Text;
        String text = "";
        try
        {

            text = File.ReadAllText(@nameArchive);

        }
        catch
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error.");
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Error line

```
byte[] datadecrypt = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
```

> Unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: The padding between characters is not valid and can not be removed.

Comment: need more info.
what's the exception message? and does it has any inner exception and what is it?

Comment: `Unicode.GetBytes(salt)` is weak, but it has to  match the encryption.

Comment: Write up a complete [mcve] with the Decryption _and_ the Encryption code.

Comment: The PaddingMode should also match that on the Encryption. But quite possibly you're mangling the Base64 somewhere along the line.

Comment: With almost no exception a padding error means that the decryption failed due to incorrect inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are base64 encoding your salt with: `resultSalt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt)` before passing it to your `Encrypt(..)` and then taking the byte value of the base64 encoded string with `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt)`. This is probably not what you want, instead pass it as a byte[], or do a proper base64 decode before you use it.

But this is not the main problem .. the main problem is that you pass the `result` to your `Decrypt(..)` instead of `resultSalt`. But when you do that, you need to ensure that it's the same as used on the `Encrypt(..)` .. currently you generate a new salt on each click.

Comment: this solves my problem